# ImportError: No module named 'RPI' の対処方法

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi

こんにちは。Raspberry Piです。
ImportError: No module named 'RPI' の対処方法について。

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get upgrade -y
$sudo apt-get dist-upgarde
$sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio
```

を行い、最新バージョンに更新できました。

次に、LEDのチカチカを行うために、led.pyを作成しました。

```
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(3, True)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(3, False)
    time.sleep(1)
```

次に`$sudo python3 led.py`を実行すると以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "led.py", line 1, in <module>
  import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named 'RPI'
```

インストールも全て行いましたが、上記のエラーが発生します。
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コードスニペットの方では `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` ですが、エラーの文は`import RPI.GPIO as GPIO`というように `RPi` のiが大文字になっているようです。こちらtypoなどでしょうか？

Comment: stack overflow へ転写を間違えました。元のプログラムは import RPI.GPIO as GPIO と書かれています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import RPI.GPIO as GPIO`

この記述は誤りで、

`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`

とする必要があります（RPiのiを小文字にする必要があります）

> `packages         = ['RPi','RPi.GPIO'],`
>   https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/setup.py

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。解決できました。